# Dom4j SAXReader times out parsing large files

Tags: dom4j

```
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
reader.setValidation(false);
org.dom4j.Document document = reader.read(dataStream);
```

Timeout occurs when parsing a large file. Is there an optimization or solution?